# How to transform an array of one iterface to another in angular 12

Tags: arrays, angular

JSON I am receiving from API is an array of objects, which roughly looks like

```
[{"id":1,
  "url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1/under-the-dome",
  "name":"Under the Dome",
  "type":"Scripted",
  "language":"English",
   "genres":["Drama","Science-Fiction","Thriller"],
  "status":"Ended",
  "runtime":60,
  "averageRuntime":60,
  "premiered":"2013-06-24",
  "officialSite":"http://www.cbs.com/shows/under-the-dome/",
  "schedule":{"time":"22:00","days":["Thursday"]},
  "rating":{"average":6.6},
  "weight":96,"
 }
]
```

I have defined 2 interfaces, one for my data structure (data I am receiving from api) and the other one for my destination object structure

Interface for my data structure (data from API)

```
  export interface IShowData {   
    name : string,
    genres : [string,string,string],
    img : {
      medium : string
    } 
  }
```

Interface for my destination object, this is how i need the data

```
export interface IShows {
  img : string;
  title : string;
  genre : string
}
```

My http service function to get the JSON object array from API. It works fine

```
getShowServiceData() {
    return this.httpClient.get<IShowData[]>(`http://api.tvmaze.com/shows`).pipe(
       map(data => this.transformToIshows(data)))
  }
```

transformToIshows is the function to transform the array from one form to another

```
private transformToIshows(data : IShowData[]) : IShows[] {
    
    const mapItems = (item:IShowData):IShows[] => {
      return {
        title : item.name,
        img: item.img.medium,
        genre : item.genres[0]

      }
    }
  }
```

It doesn't compile. Type '{ title: string; img: string; genre: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IShows[]'.I am really stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please fix the formatting of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the problem `const mapItems = (item:IShowData):**IShows[]** => {`
you are trying to return array while creating IShows object.
I have simplified transformToIshows method as below

```
transformToIshows(data: IShowData[]): IShows[] {
const list = [];
data.map(item => {
  list.push({title: item.name,
    img: item.img.medium,
    genre: item.genres[0]});
});
return list;}
```